# Converting an array into a nested object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, tree

I have typical organization `hierarchy`. For example.

```
D,E is reporting to B. B,C is reporting to A.
```

A is the top most node. But I receive this data as a flat array with an attribute pointing to the parent.

```
    [{
      name: "A",
      parent: null
    },
    {
      name: "B",
      parent: "A"
    },
    {
      name: "C",
      parent: "A"
    },
    {
      name: "D",
      parent: "B"
    },
    {
      name: "E",
      parent: "B"
    }]
```

But I want to convert this in to `single nested object` or a `tree`. A root node has children attribute with the children embedded and each child has its own children attribute like this.

```
    {
      name: "A",
      children: [{
        name: "C"
        children: [{
          name: "D"
        },{
          name: "E"
        }]
      },{
        name: "C"
      }]
    }
```

How can I do this in javascript efficiently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike the other solutions, this uses a single loop - the order of data is unimportant - example is not in the same order as question

```
var peeps = [
    { name: "D", parent: "B" }, 
    { name: "B", parent: "A" },
    { name: "A", parent: null }, 
    { name: "C", parent: "A" }, 
    { name: "E", parent: "B" }
];

var tree;
var obj = {};
peeps.forEach(function (peep) {
    var name = peep.name,
        parent = peep.parent,
        a = obj[name] || { name: name };
    if (parent) {
        obj[parent] = obj[parent] || { name: parent };
        obj[parent].children = obj[parent].children || [];
        obj[parent].children.push(a);
    } else {
        tree = obj[name];
    }
    obj[name] = obj[name] || a;
});
console.log(tree);
```

Comment: A small annotation on `a = obj[name] || { name: name };` here you can use peep instead of the new object and replace `a` with `obj[name]`, complete `obj[name] = obj[name] || peep;` where `a` use just `obj[name]` now you can delete the last line `obj[name] = obj[name] || a;`.

Comment: @NinaScholz Not sure about that. Have you tried it? For a start, the output format doesn't  include `parent` property. Also, there's method behind the apparent madness of the code to allow the input data to be in arbitrary order

Comment: it works, pl see my answer. you are right regarding the property `parent`, i include just all properties. (op does not ask them).

Answer (score 4):

This solution features Jaromanda X' [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34681055/1447675) with some additions.

1. `Array.prototype.reduce` instead of `Array.prototype.forEach`, because of the need of a temporary variable and the return value.
2. The content of `r[a.name].children` is preserved and assigned to `a.children`.
3. Node `a` is assigned to `r[a.name]`. Therefore all properties of the node object remain, like `prop1` ... `prop5`.
4. The root node is assigned to `r._` for later use.

```js
var data = [
        { name: "D", parent: "B", prop1: 'prop1' },
        { name: "B", parent: "A", prop2: 'prop2' },
        { name: "A", parent: null, prop3: 'prop3' },
        { name: "C", parent: "A", prop4: 'prop4' },
        { name: "E", parent: "B", prop5: 'prop5' }
    ],
    tree = data.reduce(function (r, a) {
        a.children = r[a.name] && r[a.name].children;
        r[a.name] = a;
        if (a.parent) {
            r[a.parent] = r[a.parent] || {};
            r[a.parent].children = r[a.parent].children || [];
            r[a.parent].children.push(a);
        } else {
            r._ = a;
        }
        return r;
    }, {})._;
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(tree, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

For more than one roots, you could use the parent of root as accessor for the children and return this array

```js
var data = [{ name: "D", parent: "B", prop1: 'prop1' }, { name: "B", parent: "A", prop2: 'prop2' }, { name: "A", parent: null, prop3: 'prop3' }, { name: "C", parent: "A", prop4: 'prop4' }, { name: "E", parent: "B", prop5: 'prop5' }, { name: "A1", parent: null, prop3: 'prop3' }],
    tree = data.reduce(function (r, a) {
        if (r[a.name] && r[a.name].children) { // prevent empty children array
            a.children = r[a.name].children;
        }
        r[a.name] = a;
        r[a.parent] = r[a.parent] || {};
        r[a.parent].children = r[a.parent].children || [];
        r[a.parent].children.push(a);
        return r;
    }, {}).null.children; // take root value as property accessor

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I had similar code, using reduce, and a "special" property on the reduction var, even called it `_` - I thought it just may be a little overwhelming for the OP - however I still used my logic to return the exact structure requested :p

Comment: Sorry for necroposting, but..Your both codes not working if there are some Root comments and not only one, where parent is Null.

Comment: @DenimTornado, please see part 2 for more than one root element.

Comment: @NinaScholz cool, it works, just one moment, can you clarify that ".null.children;" part at the end?

Comment: `r[a.parent]` creates a property with `'null'` (`null` as string as all keys are strings) as key, which is the known symbol for a root object. this is is taken to get the children of it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using while loop:

```
var data = [
    { name: "A", parent: null },
    { name: "B", parent: "A" },
    { name: "C", parent: "A" },
    { name: "D", parent: "B" },
    { name: "E", parent: "B" }
];

var root = data.find(function(item) {
    return item.parent === null;
});

var tree = {
    name: root.name
};

var parents = [tree];
while (parents.length > 0) {
    var newParents = [];
    parents.forEach(function(parent) {
        var childs = data.filter(function(item) {
            return item.parent == parent.name
        }).forEach(function(child) {
            var c = { name: child.name };
            parent.children = parent.children || [];
            parent.children.push(c);
            newParents.push(c);
        });
    });
    parents = newParents;
}

console.log(tree);
```

Comment: This will fail if the provided array is not in the correct order.

var data = [,
    { name: "B", parent: "A" },
    { name: "A", parent: null },
    { name: "C", parent: "A" },
    { name: "D", parent: "B" },
    { name: "E", parent: "B" }
];

will break for example.

Comment: @SimonBrahan no it won't fail. You forgot to remove comma in your data.

Comment: @madox2,  It should be `console.log(tree)`, right? Could you explain how this works? You are not modifying the tree object anywhere but the result is in tree. I am confused.

Comment: @espeirasbora you are right, that was kind of misstyping. I approved edit to fix it